# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()Lorg/apache/avro/LogicalType; Structured streaming with Avro data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark 2.3.1 and kafka 0.10 with below dependencies,
kafka-avro-serializer-3.2.1.jar,
kafka-schema-registry-client-3.2.1.jar,
avro-1.8.1.jar,
spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0.jar,
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar,
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar

Working on Structured streaming in 2.3 with 2.4 libraries to use from_avro as below.

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val jsonFormatSchema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("schema.avsc")))

val rawTopicMessageDF = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers).
     option("subscribe", topic).
     option("avroSchema",jsonFormatSchema).
     option("startingOffsets", "latest").
     option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 20).load()

val output = rawTopicMessageDF.select(from_avro('value, jsonFormatSchema) as 'user)
```

I see below error when I select value from rawTopicMessageDF.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()Lorg/apache/avro/LogicalType;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$.toSqlTypeHelper(SchemaConverters.scala:51)
```

can some one please help fix this issue

Comment: Please try using avro-1.7.7.jar

Comment: How do you define the dependencies? Do you use any build tool? If not, you ran into a dependency mismatch issue. Why do you use kafka-avro-serializer-3.2.1.jar, kafka-schema-registry-client-3.2.1.jar?